# text gets shown as question marks (html error page) (nginx + elastic beanstalk)

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

UPDATE:

locally the config file that has the html pages code, has `utf-8` encoding. But the files individually on elastic beanstalk instances have `us-ascii` encoding, like 40x.html and 50x.html

I have custom error pages for 40x and 50x errors defined as follows:

```
files:
  "/usr/share/nginx/html/40x.html" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: nginx
    group: nginx
    content: |
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
               <head>
                        <title>الموقع في حالة صيانة</title>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

                        <style type="text/css">
                            body { text-align: center; padding: 10%; font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
                            h1 { font-size: 50px; margin: 0; }
                            article { display: block; text-align: right; max-width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
                            a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
                            a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
                            @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
                                    h1 { font-size: 40px; }
                            }
                        </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                     <article dir="rtl">
                        <h1>لم نتمكن من العثور على تلك الصفحة.</h1>
                        <p>الصفحة التي تبحث عنها بعيدة عن متناولنا</p>
                      </article>
                </body>
        </html>
```

And in customnginx:

```
        error_page 400 404 /40x.html;
        location = /40x.html {
            limit_req zone=nginx_main burst=20 nodelay;
            limit_req_status 444;
            charset utf-8;
            source_charset utf-8;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            limit_req zone=nginx_main burst=20 nodelay;
            limit_req_status 444;
            charset utf-8;
            source_charset utf-8;
        }
```

As you can see, I have set both `charset utf-8;` and `source_charset utf-8;`

Also the html pages have UTF-8 charset.

The problem is that currently, the arabic characters above get displayed as question marks.

Answer (score 0):

you have the UTF-8 meta-tag in your files That's necessary but not enough! You also need:

#### 1- Files to be encoded in UTF-8

most text editors (such as Notepad++) allow you to alter the file charset, make sure your files are encoded in UTF-8.

#### 2- HTTP header

in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` you need this:

```
http {
    charset utf-8;
}
```

to deliver content properly.

Comment: I already have tried #2, but trying #1 didn't actually solve the problem. I used Notepad++ wine from Ubuntu software. But I couldn't type any arabic characters in that file, although it was UTF-8.

Comment: I think it could help if you try my code above and see the issue for yourself if it's possible.